# How do i figure out the multiple of a number python

Tags: python, numbers

ok, I am studying python in my computing course and i have been challenged with designing a code which validates a GTIN-8 code, I have came to a hurdle that i can not jump. I have looked on how to find the equal or higher multiple of a 10 and i have had no success so far, hope you guys can help me!

Here is a small piece of code, i need to find the equal or higher multiple of 10;

> ```
> NewNumber = (NewGtin_1 + Gtin_2 + NewGtin_3 + Gtin_4 + NewGtin_5 + Gtin_6 + NewGtin_7)
> print (NewNumber)
> ```

Comment: 10*2 = 20. What is the issue? I think I didn't got the issue. It will be great if you could explain a little bit with example.

Comment: Yes that is very unclear: the nearest multiple of 10 is 10 itself, and the next higher multiple is twice that.

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri in my code i have to find the equal or higher multiple of 10, here is a small portion of my code, I need to find the nearest higher or equal multiple of 10 of NewNumber
     'NewNumber = (NewGtin_1 + Gtin_2 + NewGtin_3 + Gtin_4 + NewGtin_5 + Gtin_6 + NewGtin_7) 
      print (NewNumber)'

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way, involving no functions and modules, could be using floor division operator `//`.

```
def neareast_higher_multiple_10(number):
    return ((number // 10) + 1) * 10
```

Examples of usage:

```
>>> neareast_higher_multiple_10(15)
20
>>> neareast_higher_multiple_10(21)
30
>>> neareast_higher_multiple_10(20.1)
30.0
>>> neareast_higher_multiple_10(20)
30
```

We can also make a generalized version:

```
def neareast_higher_multiple(number, mult_of):
    return ((number // mult_of) + 1) * mult_of
```

If you need nearest lower multiple, just remove `+ 1`:

```
def neareast_lower_multiple(number, mult_of):
    return (number // mult_of) * mult_of
```

To find the nearest multiple, you can call both these functions and use that one with a lower difference from the original number.